# Python list comprehension not working for itertools.groupby decoding

Tags: python, group-by, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I am trying to decode the result of an `itertools.groupby` into a list of values.

My source is :

```
x = [(1, 2), (2, 1), (6, 3), (6, 5), (1, 3)]
```

While the original method is to do it with a for statement like this:

```
keyfunc = itemgetter(0)
groups = []
uniquekeys = []
data = sorted(x, key=keyfunc)
for k, g in itertools.groupby(data, keyfunc):
    groups.append(list(g))      # Store group iterator as a list
    uniquekeys.append(k)
```

I opt for using list comprehension to make it in one line as:

```
[(k, list(g)) for k, g in list(itertools.groupby(x, keyfunc))]
```

The result of the first method is:

```
[1, 2, 6] #for uniquekeys
[[(1, 2), (1, 3)], [(2, 1)], [(6, 3), (6, 5)]] #for groups
```

Which totally makes sense.

The result of the second method is:

```
[(1, []), (2, []), (6, [(6, 5)])]
```

Where we can see the groups are either empty or holding single integers.

Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Just use `[(k, list(g)) for k, g in itertools.groupby(x, keyfunc)]`

Comment: Thanks @ThierryLathuille, Works!

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Why does that make a difference though?

Comment: I'll try to write an explanation as soon as possible...

Comment: It's because you are calling `list` on the `groupby` iterator, which exhausts it. Calling list on it then `iterator` and *then* iterating over it defeats the whole purpose... Why did you expect it was necessary?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga actually this code was result of a run of attempts so the `list` got there in mistake. I didn't notice.

Comment: Right explanation @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: It's actually mentioned in the docs: *"The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with groupby(). Because the source is shared, when the groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible."*

Comment: @HasanBaidoon understandable. But it should be a big red flag when you see something like that. So, I see this sometimes and it almost makes me cry `[<some_expression> for i in list(range(10))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the list in `list(itertools.groupby(x, keyfunc))`. Just drop it and it should work.

The `list(itertools...` has four iterators in your example which all share the same underlying iterator. By constructing the list, you effectively exhausted the first three iterators to create the fourth, rendering the whole thing unusable. By dropping the explicit list, you step from iterator to iterator.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.