# How to group numbers between two occurences of a number using itertools.groupby

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have a list that looks like this -

```
nums = [0,0,0,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,0]
```

I want to get the numbers between the 0s in the list. For this, I used the code below -

```
groups = list(itertools.groupby(nums, lambda item:item != 0))
groups = list(filter(lambda item:item[0], groups))
list(map(lambda item:list(item[-1]), groups))
```

But I am getting empty lists as the output -

```
[[], []]
```

My desired output is -

```
[[1,1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

How can I do this using `itertools.groupby`?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454953/python-list-comprehension-not-working-for-itertools-groupby-decoding This is a common gotcha, so there *should* be an existing canonical duplicate, but I'm not able to find one right now.

Comment: [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48475888/12671057)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I knew that there would be a similar question that has already been asked, but was just not able to find it even after 30 minutes.

Comment: There's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-itertools-groupby, which could presumably solve the problem if you looked at the examples; but the title is misleading - it's written for OP's rather specific circumstance, and only accidentally avoids the gotcha by the choice of coding style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
from itertools import groupby

nums = [0,0,0,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,0]

output = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(nums, lambda x: x != 0) if k]
print(output) # [[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

The [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) puts

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with `groupby()`. Because the source is shared, when the `groupby()` object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible.

Therefore my guest is that the first line

```py
groups = list(itertools.groupby(nums, lambda item:item != 0))
```

is the culprit. As `list` iterates over `groupby` object, each group in it also gets consumed. You can instead use

```py
groups = [(k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(nums, lambda x: x != 0)]
```

to store the result.

---

To see this:

```py
groups = groupby(nums, lambda x: x != 0)
k1, g1 = next(groups)
print(k1, list(g1)) # False [0, 0, 0, 0]

groups = groupby(nums, lambda x: x != 0)
k1, g1 = next(groups)
k2, g2 = next(groups)
print(k1, list(g1), k2, list(g2)) # False [] True [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: It wasn't working because I converted the groupby output to a list??

Comment: @Zero I guess so; [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) puts "The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with `groupby()`. Because the source is shared, when the `groupby()` object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible."

Comment: @Zero Thank you for the question; I didn't know about this behavior, and got puzzled after I first wrote my version of code. I learned from your question.